# onclick div should remove class and add class but when click on other div the first div class should be removed

Tags: jquery

onclick div should removeclass and addclass but when click on other div the first div class should be removed and add class to second div. let suppose i have gallery based on jquery. when clicks on it thumbnail, the thumbnail should act like its be selected. when i click on another thumbnail it should select the 2nd thumbnail and deselect the 1st thumbnail with .css().

Here is the thumnail html structure i am using..

```
<div class="team-pic">
    <div class="pic-corner"> </div>
    <!-- end pic-corner -->
    <a class="showSingle" target="1"><img src="images/pic-1.jpg" alt=" "></a>
</div>
```

their are lots of divs have class="team-pic". using the same html structure. how can i do it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<div class="team-pic">
     <a class="showSingle" target="1">
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50&text=1" alt=" " />
     </a>
     <a class="showSingle" target="2">
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50&text=2" alt=" " />
     </a>
     <a class="showSingle" target="3">
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50&text=3" alt=" " />
     </a>
     <a class="showSingle" target="4">
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50&text=4" alt=" " />
     </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{

    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.team-pic a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).find('img').addClass('selected');
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YjD3Y/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`.selectable` are all the divs in your gallery. `.selected` is the currently selected div.

```
$('.selectable').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
         $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```